# Can I read the html of an AJAX POST redirect?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a form that's successfully posting a lead from a form to the action URL. In order to continue to work with the details after the lead is posted I need to read a "LeadID" which is displayed on an html page.

Can I read the HTML from the redirect if the lead is posted via AJAX? The html isn't loaded by the browser so I'm confused.

I would need to read from this plain text:

```
{"code":1,"response":"OK","info":[],"leadId":XXXXXXXXX,"processTime":0.14,"timestamp":"2018-02-16T15:06:35Z"}
```

I can then use LeadID to update the lead via another post later on

Even just the relevant keywords to help my googling would help

Comment: What do you mean by _“the html isn't loaded by the browser”_ ...? Are you talking about an actual HTTP redirect, or a meta refresh, or …?

Comment: Sending an AJAX request always makes the server's response available, POST or not. All you need is `JSON.parse(response).leadId`

Answer (score 0):

When a redirect is involved there are two responses:

1. The response with the redirect header. This is usually an HTML document explaining that the user should go to a different URL. This is provided for the benefit of clients which do not automatically follow redirects.
2. The response for the URL that the redirect points to.

XMLHttpRequest and fetch will transparently follow redirects.

The response to 1 will not be made available to JavaScript.

The response to 2 will be as if it were the response to 1 (and subject to the usual limitations of the same origin policy and so on).